# urlopen fails, urlretrieve works

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.7.0 to retrieve and save favicon.ico files from several thousand URLs, some of which are bad. To be efficient, I try to test each URL before trying to retrieve the image, using this code:

```
url_parts = urlparse(url)
status_code = urllib.request.urlopen(url_parts.scheme + "://" + url_parts.netloc).getcode()
```

If the returned `status_code` is 2xx, I then call:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_parts.scheme + "://" + url_parts.netloc + "/favicon.ico", local_path)
```

`local_path` is a previously assigned unique path\name for the favicon (which doesn't always exist on the site, but the code recovers gracefully in such cases). The weirdness is that `urlretrieve` always works when the site exists, but `urlopen` often (but not always) throws an exception for the same site.

Does anyone know why `urlopen` sometimes fails, or how to create a test that works?

Comment: Try to catch the error, could be HTTPS,( SSL connection). Delay reaching the site.

Comment: This is happening consistently on the same (many) sites. The URL that always works fine in a browser and with `urlretrieve` still fails with `urlopen`, all within a few seconds of each other.

Comment: A warning sign is that you're generating new URLs using `+`. It's better to use `urlunparse`, `urljoin`,  and friends.

Comment: I'm printing out the URLs as they're generated. e.g. `https://stackoverflow.com`. My program had no problem retrieving `https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico`.